# How to show NotifyIcon permanently?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My project takes 30 minutes to complete.
How to show `NotifyIcon` during 30 minutes?

Following code works 5 seconds even you adjust 3000000:

```
NotifyIcon1.Text = "Something"
NotifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Everything"
NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(3000000)
```

Comment: It matters, because a NotifyIcon is not a "message" then your question is wrong.

Comment: Showing NotifyIcon permanently is *not* a problem.  It is spamming the user with a balloon that is subject to a timeout.  If there wasn't one then you would have to compete with other programmers that think like you and also want to show their balloons forever, a battle that nobody wins.  Only the user loses.  And of course this is not a problem at all, your user has something much better to do than staring at your balloon for half an hour.

Comment: *- What's the purpose of showing such message?*
  Think about the purpose of showing such message for a long time to the user and maybe you will find a better solution for that purpose. Showing a tip permanently is annoying for the users. 
 *- Have you ever seen such behavior in windows or some standard and famous application?*
   Avoid using solutions that you have never seen. Such solution is not user friendly and is against standard UI design guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it.

As stated in documents The minimum and maximum time of showing that tip is an OS feature and values that are too large or too small are adjusted to the appropriate minimum or maximum value.

> [**NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms160065(v=vs.100).aspx)
>
> Minimum and maximum timeout values are enforced by the operating
>   system and are typically 10 and 30 seconds, respectively, however this
>   can vary depending on the operating system. Timeout values that are
>   too large or too small are adjusted to the appropriate minimum or
>   maximum value. In addition, if the user does not appear to be using
>   the computer (no keyboard or mouse events are occurring) then the
>   system does not count this time towards the timeout.

Comment: @HerryMarkowitz  Which bit of 'Minimum and Maximum timeout values are enforced by the operating system and are typically 10 and 30 seconds' don't you understand? A notify icon simply won't work.  Reza has provided a workable workaround, but no end user is going to sit and look at anything for thirty minutes anyway without thinking that something has gone seriously wrong, so logic dictates you have a rethink about what you're doing in the first place and if the only solution is to have them wait then provide some sort of progress indicator.

Comment: @DomSinclair Thank you for your comment, I edited the post a bit and removed the workaround because it may mislead users. It think the answer is better now. Hope you find it useful :)